# Not getting SQL Statement output using ELK logstash jdbc plugin

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, metricbeat

Trying to get output using logstash with jdbc plugin but not getting data. Try different way to get pg_stat_replication data. But at Index Management did not found that index where my index name is pg_stat_replication.
Conf. file path  /etc/logstash/conf.d/postgresql.conf

```
input {
        # pg_stat_replication;
        jdbc {
                jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/postgresql-jdbc.jar"
                jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
                jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.43.21:5432/postgres"
                jdbc_user => "postgres"
                jdbc_password => "p"
                statement => "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication"
                schedule => "* * * * *"
                type => "pg_stat_replication"
        }


}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "http://192.168.43.100:9200"
                index => "%{type}"
                user => "elastic"
                password => "abc@123"

        }
}
~
```